# Spring Batch not commit, not terminate Problem(Only Single Item Commit Successfully)

Tags: spring-batch, spring-boot-3

I'm upgrading the SpringBoot version of the project from 2.7.6 to 3.1.5. The version of SpringBatch is also going up to 5, causing the following problems.

Spring Batch Process is not shutting down. Through the show-sql setting, we have confirmed that query occurs normally in the internal logic of the ItemWriter, but this is not commited and remains in a non-terminated state.

What's more unusual is that when I run only one item, it is normally commited and terminated.
Also, if there are multiple chunks that need to be committed, only the last chunk is not being committed.

I think there's a problem with the datasource and txManager setup but I'm really curious about what's wrong. Please help me..

```
@Configuration
public class BatchDBConfiguration
        extends DefaultBatchConfiguration {

    @BatchDataSource
    @Bean(name = "jobDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource jobDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource getDataSource() {
        return this.jobDataSource();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager jobTransactionManager() {
        return new JdbcTransactionManager(getDataSource());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected ExecutionContextSerializer getExecutionContextSerializer() {
        return new Jackson2ExecutionContextStringSerializer();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.batch.job", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
    public JobLauncherApplicationRunner jobLauncherApplicationRunner(JobLauncher jobLauncher, JobExplorer jobExplorer,
                                                                     JobRepository jobRepository, BatchProperties properties) {
        JobLauncherApplicationRunner runner = new JobLauncherApplicationRunner(jobLauncher, jobExplorer, jobRepository);
        String jobNames = properties.getJob().getName();

        if (StringUtils.hasText(jobNames)) {
            runner.setJobName(jobNames);
        }

        return runner;
    }
}
```

```
@EnableTask
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class UserBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(UserBatchApplication.class);
        application.setWebApplicationType(WebApplicationType.NONE);
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(application.run(args)));
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = BatchProperties.class)
public class ExpireAdultCertificationBatchConfig {

    private final PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager;
    private final JobRepository jobRepository;
    private final ExpireAdultCertification expireAdultCertification;

    public ExpireAdultCertificationBatchConfig(
            @Qualifier("transactionManager") PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager,
            JobRepository jobRepository,
            ExpireAdultCertification expireAdultCertification) {
        this.platformTransactionManager = platformTransactionManager;
        this.jobRepository = jobRepository;
        this.expireAdultCertification = expireAdultCertification;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job expireAdultCertificationJob() {
        return new JobBuilder("expireAdultCertificationJob", jobRepository)
                .preventRestart()
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(expireAdultCertificationJobStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @JobScope
    public Step expireAdultCertificationJobStep() {
        return new StepBuilder("expireAdultCertificationStep", jobRepository)
                .tasklet(expireAdultCertificationTasklet(), platformTransactionManager)
                .transactionManager(platformTransactionManager)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Tasklet expireAdultCertificationTasklet() {
        return (contribution, chunkContext) -> {
            expireAdultCertification.execute();
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        };
    }
}
```